# Win32 C - Parent window losing track of child window

Tags: c, winapi, win32gui

I'm trying to create popout windows (like the dockable panes in Visual Studio). I have a wrapper window (which I'll call a 'view') containing my controls which I'm able to popout into a seperate window. The attaching and detaching is done using custom messages and handled in the `WndProc` of the view window itself.

The top-level/main window also needs to control the state of the view window (from toolbars etc). However because the view changes its own parent when it detaches, the main window loses track of the `HWND` of the view and therefore cannot be retrieved using `GetDlgItem()`. I understand that `FindWindow()` is not appropriate for this as it doesn't find child windows.

I've thought about assigning custom user data in `cbWndExtra` of the main window to store the handles of all the views (and updating them with `WM_NOTIFY`), but I'm not sure if this is the best way to proceed with this.

Looking for any advice on this matter. Thanks.

If it is of use, the current attach and detach code:

```
case WM_ATTACH:
{
    DWEI* td = (DWEI*)GetWindowLongPtr(hwnd, 0);
    if (!(td->flags & VIEW_DETACHED))
        break;

    HWND hPane = GetParent(hwnd);   //The parent will/should be the pane window.
    //Save the last detached coordinates.
    RECT rcView;
    GetWindowRect(hPane, &rcView);
    td->rcPreviousDetachedLocation = rcView;

    RECT pal = td->rcPreviousAttachedLocation;
    //HWND_BOTTOM otherwise it messes up. Move it before changing parents to avoid graphical jolts.
    SetWindowPos(hwnd, HWND_BOTTOM, pal.left, pal.top, pal.right - pal.left, pal.bottom - pal.top, NULL);
    //Set the view back to the main window.
    SetParent(hwnd, td->hAttachedParent);

    //Clear the detached flag because now it's attached.
    td->flags &= ~VIEW_DETACHED;

    SendMessage(hPane, WM_CLOSE, 0, 0);
    break;
}
case WM_DETACH:
{
    //Check parent child heirachy before creating a new parent window.
    DWEI* td = (DWEI*)GetWindowLongPtr(hwnd, 0);
    //Check if it's not already detached.
    if (td->flags & VIEW_DETACHED)
        break;  //If it's already detached.

    RECT attachedlocation;
    GetWindowRect(hwnd, &attachedlocation);
    MapWindowPoints(HWND_DESKTOP, td->hAttachedParent, (LPPOINT)&attachedlocation, 2);  //Convert to client coordinates.
    td->rcPreviousAttachedLocation = attachedlocation;      //Remember the last attached position.

    HWND pane = CreatePane_Empty(td);
    SetParent(hwnd, pane);
    RECT rcPane;
    GetClientRect(pane, &rcPane);
    //Reposition the wrapper to the pane.
    SetWindowPos(hwnd, HWND_TOP, rcPane.left, rcPane.top, rcPane.right, rcPane.bottom, NULL);

    //Set the detached flag so it's considered detached.
    td->flags ^= VIEW_DETACHED;
    break;
}
```

Comment: The title of the question is just heart-breaking.

Comment: There are a number of ways you could do this. Creating a data structure and storing a pointer to it in the extra window data, or as a window property via `SetProp`, is extremely common and probably the best option.

Comment: Thanks I'll try that. Would you say the problem I'm having is a result of poor code architecture or is this just how it's done with this sort of thing?

Comment: You need to keep track of the windows somehow. When they're child windows the system maintains the connection for you. There are other ways you could do it but there's nothing wrong with storing a pointer to a data structure.